# Clustering samples from non-stationary multivariate distributions

Tags: distributions, clustering, multivariate-analysis, expectation-maximization

I have dataset consisting of samples from a n-multivariate probability distribution, i.e each sample is a n-dimensional vector. The data source is known to be non-stationary in nature. I have been looking for ways to cluster the samples into subsets such that each subset represents at least a covariance or weakly stationary distribution. What are some effective ways of doing so?

Essentially all of the clustering methods I've come across thus far are based on geometry instead of statistical basis.

Comment: Then you must have overlooked EM clustering...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but EM assumes a mixture of gaussian. I prefer not to make such assumptions.

Comment: Statistics requires assumptions. You can do EM with other distributions as well, it's just that nobody seems to use that in practise. Either way it is not "based on geometry". And in fact, **EM uses covariances**.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Then you must have overlooked EM clustering... – Anony-Mousse

Correct me if I'm wrong but EM assumes a mixture of gaussian. I prefer not to make such assumptions. – gamerx

Statistics requires assumptions. You can do EM with other distributions as well, it's just that nobody seems to use that in practise. Either way it is not "based on geometry". And in fact, EM uses covariances. – Anony-Mousse